# Cone light direction Degree parameter doing nothing what ever value i give?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

coneLight = new ConeLight(rayHandler,100,Color.WHITE,200/PPM,0,0,30,30);
[At directionDegree = 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYWtK.png)

```
    coneLight = new ConeLight(rayHandler,100,Color.WHITE,200/PPM,0,0,60,30);
```

[At directionDegree = 60](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVtqD.png)

```
    coneLight = new ConeLight(rayHandler,100,Color.WHITE,200/PPM,0,0,130,30);
```

[At directionDegree = 130](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVDo7.png)

why the same result is coming in all case(different values of direction degrees)?

Comment: It looks like you are attaching the light to a body. This overwrites the angle offset. To add an offset when attaching to a body user coneLight.attach(body, x, y, degrees).

Comment: thanks ...it worked....and can you please tell me how many types of lights are there in box2D related to libgdx

Comment: The only ones I used were, point, cone, directional and chain light. Not sure if there are any others. You could check the src on github https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights

Comment: @dfour thanks for the help...can you please do me one last favour ...actually i have been struggling with this issue from so many days...can you please answer this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858339/why-directionallight-is-not-casting-shadow) that would have been a great help for me...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching a Light to a body will cause the light to ignore any angle offsets set to the light.

In order to add an angle offset when attaching to a body use

```
light.attach(body, x, y, degrees);
```