# why DirectionalLight is not casting shadow?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

Code:

```
Color color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,0.9f);
DirectionalLight directionalLight = new DirectionalLight(rayHandler,200,color,-90f);
directionalLight.setSoftnessLength(0);
```

Result:
[image: Screenshot]

When light falls directly from above, why it is not casting shadows from boxes?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51858339/edit) to include more information.

Comment: I tried both -89 and -91 but the problem still persist...and what u did to adjust the brightness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by a few things. Some things to check:

1. Check if your RayHandler is set to blur. Blurring with small objects can hide shadows.
2. Check the Shadows are enabled in the ray handler.
3. Check the ambient light is off or lower than the directional light. If ambient light is too high it may hide shadows.
4. Check your objects are larger than 0.1f as this is the smallest distance box2dlights works with
5. Check the light is not set to x-ray
6. check softness length. lights with high softness will have their light bleed through small objects.

Comment: It worked when i changed the size of boxes to 1 ..I think this is the minimum size required by directional light to cast shadows....thanks for all the help

Comment: I've added another check based on your comment. The default softness is 2.5f for a light. try changing it to a lower value and see if it affects your shadows.